# Migrate from Parse.com to Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, cordova, heroku

I'm trying to figure out the steps involved to migrate an app from Parse.com to Heroku I found this:

https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/

I'm new to Cordova and parse so I have some questions:
Can Heroku host a MongoDB instance as well as a Parse server, or do I have to get MongoDB somewhere else (mLab, MongoDB Atlas, etc)

This for a Cordova app. Is that valid to migrate to Heroku? I just need a replacement for Parse.com. Thanks.

Comment: heroku has concept of add-ons.. you can install mongolabs and move your data from parse.com to mongolabs http://cycorax-tech.blogspot.com/ has blog to move parse.com data to mongolabs

Comment: Thanks, that helped me out. The mLab add on to heroku worked for me.